# Проблема с nodejs на VPS сервере

Tags: node.js, vps

Проблема с nodejs на VPS сервере, когда я запускаю его я получаю ошибку (Error: Cannot find module 'util / types'), но когда я запускаю нод на локалхосте, то нет такой проблемы
Я уже пробовал обновлять и понижать версию нода, так же его сносил и ставил заново

Comment: попробуйте разобраться с тем, что за модуль util / types и откуда от берется

Comment: Почитай [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323472/cannot-find-module-internal-util-types)